# How to draw table as result in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

```
   <body onload="getCd()">
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <input type="text" id="ajax" list="json-datalist">
            <datalist id="json-datalist"></datalist>
        </div>
function getCd() {
        var url, option;
        url = 'catolog.json';
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $(data.CATALOG.CD).each(function() {
        option = "<option value=\"" + this.TITLE + "\">" +    this.ARTIST + " " + 
        this.YEAR +"  " + this.PRICE + " " + this.COUNTRY + "   </option>";
        $('#json-datalist').append(option);
        });
        });
        });
        }
```

This is my currently working script, I need to transform the `datalist` into an HTML `table`.

Comment: Please try to explain your question further.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are appending `option` tags into an `datalist` tag.

If you want a plain old HTML table, simply replace the `option` with something like:

```
'<tr><td>this.TITLE</td><td>this.ARTISTS</td><td>this.YEAR</td>....</tr>'
```

and replace the `datalist` with:

```
<table id='json-datalist"></table>
```